# Stuck Windows Key on Windows 2008 server (via mstsc)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

I'm connecting to a Windows 2008 R2 server using terminal services. It worked like a charm for a very long time, but now for some reason the Windows Key seems to be stuck in it.
(No matter where I connect from)

So for example, if I press "L" the screen locks.
It makes it impossible to work with the server.
And I've had this with other servers in the past as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bounce the server? Or if you cant, restart the "Remote Desktop Services" service?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/5480/remote-desktop-pressing-windows-key-randomly

Answer (score 2):

open on-screen keyboard and press the window key. it will get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before. Not sure what causes it, but double tapping the windows key seems to fix it.

Comment: Same here, failing that slam the windows key multiple times & the escape key for good measure

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well, and tapping the windows key or control key did not work to fix it, not did using the on-screen keyboard.

I think the issue for me is that I am using it with the RemoteApp option. 
I did finally find a solution [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/5480/remote-desktop-pressing-windows-key-randomly/480727#480727). Basically, in the RDP connection window, tell it to either always use windows keys on the local machine, or always on the remote machine.
I set it to always use the local, and it seemed to fix the issue, although I will know for sure in a few days.